# Declaring Dynamic array in a function

Tags: c++

I am making a function that re-allocate a new dynamic array if the previous array is full. However, If I compile it, a run-time error happens. When I debug it with Visual Studio 2015, it seems that, after function is done, the compiler cannot access to the dynamic array or the array is deleted. Can you tell me why?

```
void reallocateMemory(string* arr, int& physicalSize, int addedMemory) {
    string* result = new string[physicalSize + addedMemory];
    for (int i = 0; i < physicalSize; i++) {
        result[i] = arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;

    arr = result; // After this code, it seems variable arr works well.
    result = nullptr;
    physicalSize += addedMemory;
} // However, when the function returns, arr cannot access a dynamic array.
```

Comment: `arr = result` only assigns to the local variable `arr`. The caller doesn't get the updated pointer.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector` or something?

Comment: To @user2357112's comment, you want a `string*&` (a reference to a pointer to a `string`).  But really, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the function returns, arr cannot access a dynamic array.

Indeed. `arr` is a local variable, and will no longer exist after the function returns. The memory that you allocate within the function is leaked, since it is no longer pointed by any variable.

You need some way to pass a pointer to the newly allocated memory outside the scope of the function. Typical ways to do that are: 1) Change the return type of the function, and return the pointer 2) Pass the original pointer value as a reference, so that the function can modify the referenced pointer variable.